# path to pg_hba.conf and pg_ctl - automatic way to extract

Tags: postgresql

I am scripting some changes to pg_hba.conf and I am looking for an automatic way to find the location of it. Similarly, I need the path to pg_ctl too to reload the configuration. I can use pg_clusters to find the data directory but I cannot use it to derive location of pg_hba.conf and pg_ctl. Any suggestions?

here are the locations of these things on my ubuntu:

```
pg_hba.conf: /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
pg_ctl: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin
```

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Over a PostgreSQL protocol connection you can get the datadir, config file and hba file locations.

```
postgres=# SHOW hba_file;
              hba_file               
-------------------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)

postgres=# SHOW config_file ;
               config_file               
-----------------------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

postgres=# SHOW data_directory;
     data_directory      
-------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data
(1 row)
```

You can reload the configuration over the PostgreSQL protocol too:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_reload_conf();
 pg_reload_conf 
----------------
 t
(1 row)
```

All those details can be obtained in one `psql` invocation in `bash` (if you don't mind writing `bash` specific, non-portable shell), with correct handling of space separated values, with:

```
$ IFS='|' pgconf=($(psql -U postgres -qAt -F '|' -c "SELECT current_setting('hba_file'), current_setting('config_file'), current_setting('data_directory');"))
```

which produces a bash array containing the three values:

```
$ echo ${pgconf[0]}
/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf
$ echo ${pgconf[1]}
/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/postgresql.conf
$ echo ${pgconf[2]}
/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data
```

Comment: Thank you. One quick question - what's the default password for user postgres?

Comment: @gablubablu Depends entirely on how PostgreSQL was installed. On most Ubuntu / Fedora installs (vendor packages or PGDG packages) there is no password set, and authentication is done in `peer` mode on unix socket connections. So the unix user `postgres` can connect as PostgreSQL user `postgres`. Hence the common idiom `sudo -u postgres psql` for getting a superuser connection. Other installs, like those from EnterpriseDB, or on Windows, may differ. If you can't sudo to `postgres` and get a connection then prompt the user for details.

Comment: your comment is actually the answer I've been looking for last hour! :)